# Convertir longitud y latitud a direccion angular 5

Tags: html5, angular, typescript

Me estan mandando la longitud y la latitud de un dispositivo y yo tengo que ubicarla en un mapa eso si lo hago pero tengo que mostrar a lado del mapa la latitud, la longitud y la direccion en la que esta ese dispositivo, mi pregunta es ¿como puedo convertir esa latitud y longitud en una direccion? por ejemplo  "920 S Harwood St, Dallas, TX 75201, EE. UU." estoy usando angular google maps (https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/)

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, lo que pides se llama geocodificación, el mismo google maps provee toda la documentación y ejemplos para hacerlo con javascript, revisa [Prácticas recomendadas para la geocodificación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices?hl=es). Saludos.

Comment: Lo revisare muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar el Geocoding API, y utilizar las opciones de geocodificación inversa.

```
    const lat = 45.45121212;
    const long = 45.451564;
    const TU_LLAVE = 'TU_LLAVE';
    this.http.get<{status: string, results: any[]}>(
         `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${long}&key=${TU_LLAVE}`,
          {responseType: 'json'}
        ).subscribe(e => {
          if (e.status === 'OK') {
            console.log(e.results[0].formatted_address);
          }
        });
```

Puedes revisar la [documentación de la API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=es#ReverseGeocoding). Allí más abajo hay un ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo